# how to type in latex styled variables for julia in vs code or jupyter notebook

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia, ijulia-notebook

As in Julia REPL, we can type in latex styled variables by using `tab` and `\epsilon` to get the greek letter and give it a value. Since I mainly wirte Julia
codes in VS Code now, I was wondering if we could do that in vs code also? or can we do that in Jupyter notebook?

[image]

and in advance, can we have complicate latex styled computation formula in vs code when progrmming with the julia extension? or in Jupyter notebook

What I want to describe here is something very similar to what Mathematica can do, which makes the math equations much easier to read.

Answer (score 5):

There is a [VS Code Julia extension](https://www.julia-vscode.org/), which does support LaTeX-like tab completion, just like in the REPL. It should also just work in Jupyter, if you have the correct Julia kernel installed. You can find out more about that [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl).

In terms of a Mathematica style notebook workflow, Jupyter is probably the closest. Julia code still has to be regular Unicode text, so you can't expect your code to look exactly like free-form LaTeX, but you might want to look at [Latexify.jl](https://github.com/korsbo/Latexify.jl), which can convert Julia expressions and data structure into nice-looking LaTeX code. If you output LaTeX code generated by Latexify.jl in a Jupyter cell, it should even render correctly using MathJax. Otherwise, you can also just write LaTeX formulas inside Markdown cells with Jupyter.

Comment: thanks, so I just tried vs code, but didn't get it working by using tab and \epsilon combinations. Is there any shortcut for that?

Comment: It takes a while until LanguageServer.jl starts for the first time, you should see a notification in the bottom left if it's still loading. It's also described in this GitHub issue: https://github.com/julia-vscode/julia-vscode/issues/613